# WebGL only drawing part of a circle

Tags: webgl

Im trying to make a circle drawing method in WebGL, where i pass the Radius, center, etc. But its only drawing a part of it and im not really sure what the problem is.

Im pretty sure the problems are probably the angles im using to calculare the vertex. but i dont really see why it wpuld not work.

i´ve printed the vertex and the outputs and everything seems to be in order, so im not sure what is wrong with it.

Here is how im defining the vertex:

```
var noOfFans = 80;
var angles = (2*Math.PI)/noOfFans;
var pos = [centro[0], centro[1]];
for(var i = 0; i <= noOfFans;i++) 
  {
   var xCoord = centro[0] + (radio*Math.cos(angles*(i + 1))); 
   var yCoord = centro[1] + (radio*Math.sin(angles*(i + 1)));

    pos.push(xCoord);
    pos.push(yCoord);
  }
```

this goes to another function, which serves to feed my buffers with the needed vertex, color, and indexes:

```
function CircleBuffer(gl, ver, color)
{
  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(ver), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  var colors = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < ver.length; i++)
    {
      colors = colors.concat(color);
    }
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
  var index = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < (ver.length)/2 - 2;i++)
    {
     index = index.concat(0,i+1,i+2);
    }
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(index), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  return {
    position: positionBuffer,
    color: colorBuffer,
    indices: indexBuffer,
  };
```

It is supposed to draw a full circle, but only draw this

[image].

i also [link](https://codepen.io/agracia10/pen/PoYjPdM?editors=0011)  the pen where i have the rest of my code if needed

Comment: Why not put all of your code in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? If we can not reproduce the bug with code **in the question itself** then your question is off topic for stack overflow

Comment: As @gman said, please add a snippet.  I believe there are key parts of your code that are not being expressed in the question itself.